# NetBeans directory name changing

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I changed the folder's name where NetBeans is installed from C:\Program Files\Netbeans 8.0.2 to C:\Program Files\Netbeans8.0.2 (Notice I have deleted a space before 8.0.2) Because it was generating an error with Glassfish regarding the mysql-connector directory since the directory is written like this : C:\Program%20Files\Netbeans%208.0.2\ and I think the %208 is causing the error.
Now NetBeans doesn't work at all.
I tried to find an enviroment variable to change it but i can't find anyone.
What should I do?

Comment: Can you be a little bit more descriptive with Netbeans not working at all? What exactly do you mean??

Comment: I meant it runs but once it's opened it doesn't respond. I have to close it using the task manager and a window pops saying the Java SE is not working

Comment: Does it produce any kind of error log file?

Answer (score 0):

You can always try uninstalling NetBeans, cleaning missing registry entries (optional but advisable), and installing again.

And avoid manually renaming installation folders.

Comment: when I put the space back it works just fine.@KaiserM11

Comment: Ok. If the error is generated by the _%208_ then, the only solution it comes to my mind right now in order to avoid the Glassfish error is reinstalling Netbeans and change default installation name from _NetBeans 8.0.2_ to something like _NetBeans v8.0.2_